# Specific memory management issue in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management

Imagine the following classes in java or C#:

```
class A
{
  B b;
  //some other stuff

  public A(B b) {this.b = b;}
}

class B
{
  A createA() {return new A(this); }
}
```

then we would use it e.g.

```
A complicatedCreateA()
{
  B = new B();
  return b.createA();
}
```

and the virtual machine / CLR would make sure we don't leak memory.

How can I implement a similar pattern in C++ so that I don't leak memory and reference cleaned resources?

EDIT:
To make it more clear I am specifically worried about what happens if I call createA() more than once, and when the different objects A will have different lifetimes, e.g.:

```
A anotherMethod()
{
  B = new B();
  A a = b.createA();
  //use a locally, or use with yet another object C, etc.
  return b.createA();
}
```

I have the basic understanding how smart pointers work in C++. However, even if I do something like:

```
boost::shared_ptr<B> b(new B());
```

then I don't have access to this smart pointer from within B, so I can't pass it to A. And how otherwise A can make sure that the corresponding object B gets deleted not too late and not too early?

Comment: Using Smart Pointers ofcourse.

Comment: shared_ptr is a masterpiece, designed for garbage collection in C++. Refactored my code with it and saved a lot of time debugging mem leaks

Comment: @cateof, I love shared_ptr as well, but I don't know how to use it in this setting - please see edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact equivalent gets a little bit complicated:

```
class A
{
    std::shared_ptr<B> b;
    //some other stuff

public:
    A(std::shared_ptr<B> const & b) : b(b) {}
};

class B : public std::enable_shared_from_this<B>
{
public:
    A createA() {return A(shared_from_this());}
};

A complicatedCreateA()
{
    std::shared_ptr<B> b = std::make_shared<B>();
    return b->createA();
}
```

Alternatively, you could avoid the `shared_from_this` malarkey by making `createA` a non-member (or static member, if it needs access to `B`s privates), taking a shared pointer argument:

```
A createA(std::shared_ptr<B> const & b) {return A(b);}

A complicatedCreateA()
{
    std::shared_ptr<B> b = std::make_shared<B>();
    return createA(b);
}
```

Comment: I think that B is some kind of factory class for A and he wants to be able to polymorphically create new objects of the same type as the original (without them actually being clones).

Answer (score 3):

Either allocate them only on the stack (preferable) or (for times when you can't) use [smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one), which obviate the need for manual memory management and are exception-safe when used properly.

```
class B;

class A
{
public:
  std::unique_ptr<B> b;

  A(B b) : b(make_unique<B>(b)) { }
};

class B
{
public:
  std::unique_ptr<A> createA() { return make_unique<A>(*this); }
};
```

Then

```
std::unique_ptr<A> complicatedCreateA()
{
  B b; // or std::unique_ptr<B> bptr(make_unique<B>()); but here that's useless more work

  return b.createA();
}
```

And you don't need to call `delete` on the return value of `createA` or on the member `A::b` because whenever the `unique_ptr`s go out of scope, they will clean up the `A*` and `B*` they own.

Notice that you call `make_unique<T>` to make a `unique_ptr`. This has the advantage of being more exception-safe than plain `new`, though you can use that too, like `: b(new B(b))` and `return std::unique_ptr<A>(new A(*this));`.

There is also the reference-counted `shared_ptr` for when you need to have multiple pointers to the same object.

Comment: To be honest I am more worried about the lifetime of B (assuming I will use createA more than once). Let me edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: This differs slightly from the question, in that it copies the `B` used to create the `A`, rather than storing a reference to the same object. If you really want an exact equivalent, then you'd need a `shared_ptr<B>`, and `createA` would have to either be a non-member taking a `shared_ptr<B>` argument, or use `shared_from_this`.

Comment: @Mike ah cool, I didnt know about `shared_from_this`, thanks and +1

Answer (score 1):

It is not a simple case of saying "use smart pointers". B appears to be a factory of A. A has a pointer to the factory object that created it (and presumably can create more A-type objects from it).

If you want B to be reference-counted it has to be "intrusively" reference counted. This is usually done with some kind of addRef() / release() mechanism, and when release() is called the last time it usually performs a delete this

I might also assume that A is polymorphic in some way such that you can get an object to create more objects of its own type (not necessarily clones) through its abstract factory.

The question is, where did the first B come from that created the first A? Do you have a lot of these B objects and do you really want to get rid of it the moment your last A is deleted, or is its lifetime managed elsewhere.

With regards to the A, your B would create a new one with regular new, and then you would put it into a shared_ptr or whatever yourself.

Note that you could use a reference here, thus:

```
class A
{
 private:
    friend class B;

    explicit A( B const& b );

    B (const) & b_;

    A(const A&); // not implemented
 public:
    A* createNew() const;
    ~A();      
};

 A::A( B const& b )
     : b_( b )
 {
    b_.addRef(); // possibly, if reference counted
 }

 A::~A()
 {
    b_.release();
 }

 A* A::createNew() const
 {
    return b_.createA();
 }
```

for B

```
 A* B::createNew() const
 {
    return new A(*this); // addRef() will be invoked
 }

 void B::addRef() const
 {
    atomically_increment( &my_refCount );
 }

 void B::release() const
 {
    if( !atomically_decrement( &my_refCount ) )
        delete this;
 }
```

where B has a mutable my_refCount of the type that fits into the atomic increment/decrement call for your system.

Note that you can use boost shared_ptr for B too but will need to need to derive B from `boost::enable_shared_from_this<B>`. This is also "intrusive" but will do a lot of the work for you. Your A will now need to store a `boost::shared_ptr<B>` and  B::createA() will call `shared_from_this()`.

To do it this way, you will need to create your first B and put it into a shared_ptr to create the first A.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to boost, you can use smart pointers. Depend what you want to achieve, you can either use `boost::shared_ptr`(reference counting one) or `boost::scoped_ptr`.

Have a look at: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm

Comment: using latest g++ shared_ptr can be found in <tr1/memory> as well, no need for boost

Comment: I love shared_ptr as well, but I don't know how to use it in this setting - please see edit.

Answer (score 0):

> To make it more clear I am specifically worried about what happens if I call createA() more than once, and when the different objects A will have different lifetimes, e.g.:

```
A anotherMethod() {
    B b = new B();
    A a = b.createA();   //use a locally, or use with yet another object C, etc.           
    return b.createA();
}
```

There is no need at all to create objects with `new B();`, you can just create them on the stack and their lifetimes will be handled automatically.

Just do it like this:

```
A anotherMethod() {
    B b;
    A a = b.createA();   //use a locally, or use with yet another object C, etc.           
    return b.createA();
}
```

Unlike in some other languages, this is not references to heap objects but values that are copied. The copies will be destroyed when their respective lifetime is over. Automatically!